# Check if there are exactly 3 question marks, in the input string, between the pair of two numbers that add up to 10

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, regex

I'm just learning about the regular expressions, and found this problem on the internet.It's a nice practice for a beginner in regexp.

**Problem instruction:**

> Have the function take the string parameter which will contain single digit numbers, letters and question marks, and check if there are exactly 3 question marks between every pair of two numbers that add up to (n).

**The things I'm most interested from this code review:**

- The regexp I used is quite simple and limited. I isolated all the strings with the 3 question marks between the pair of two numbers, with it. Then I used a separate function to iterate over the array holding those strings, and checked the sum of the first and last character for each string. I'm wondering is it possible to do the checking in the regexp itself?
- Usefulness of the testing function used for the regexp search. What would be an appropriate way to test something like this?

  - Naming convention
  - Code cleanliness
  - Structuring of the code
  - Commenting of the code sample

---

```
import string
import random
import re

def str_generrator( size, chars = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits  ):
    """ Generates a random string of lowercase letters and single digit 
    numbers, with the length specified by the user.

    Arguments:
        type:<int> - An integer representing the length of the generated string.
        type:<str> - A string containing the digits and lowercase letters.
    Return:
        type:<str> - Random generated string.
    """
    return ''.join( random.SystemRandom().choice( chars ) for c in range( size ))

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
def pattern_search( str ):
    """Finds a specific string from the input using a regexp text
    string for describing a search pattern. The function will check if there
    are exactly 3 question marks between every pair of two numbers.

    Arguments:
        type:<str> - A string where the search will be preformed.
    Return:
        type:<arr> - An array containing the results of the search.
    """
    return re.findall( r'\d[A-Za-z]*?\?[A-Za-z]*?\?[A-Za-z]*?\?[A-Za-z]*?\d', str )

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def shuffle_string( string1, string2 = '???????????????????' ):
    """Joins and makes a random shuffle of two input strings.
    Creating a new string with the length of first input string.

    Arguments:
        type:<str> - Input string one
        type:<str> - Input string two
    Return:
        type:<str> - String containing mixed values of input strings.
    """
    # Concatenate the inputs, and convert it to the list.
    string = string1 + string2
    strlst = list( string )

    # Shuffles the list, converts it to the string and returns the results.
    random.SystemRandom().shuffle( strlst )
    shuffled_string = ''.join( strlst[:len( string1 )])
    return shuffled_string

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def calc_additions( num, str_arr ):
    """Calculates if the input string first and last character add up to the 
    number specified by the user.

    Arguments:
        type<int> - A required sum for the input strings characters.
        type<arr> - An array with strings on which the calculations are 
                    preformed.
    Return:
        type<arr> - An array holdin the results of the calculations.
    """

    results = []
    for string in str_arr:
        if( int( string[0] ) + int( string[-1] ) == num ):
            results.append( string )

    return results

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def main():

    search_str = ''
    patterns = []

    # Test for the regexp search.
    for c in range( 1000 ):

        search_str = shuffle_string( str_generrator(40) )
        patterns = pattern_search( search_str )

        print(' Search string  : {}'.format( search_str ))
        print(' Patterns found : {}'.format( patterns ))
        print(' Valid patterns : {}'.format( calc_additions( 10, patterns)))

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please don't put spaces after opening and before closing parens. Also, don't wrap conditions in `if` statement in parens. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ for more style guide. You don't need to "convert" string to list to call use with `join()`. Just use the string itself. `SystemRandom` might be a bit excessive for this task... it's just a test after all. Also, your regexp doesn't do what the description says. A regex cannot do this in principle, since the language you describe isn't regular. However `try: map(int, s.split('???')); return True; except: return False` would do.

Comment: @wvxvw Thank you for the comment, i will use your highlights to better optimize the code i write.

Comment: OK, I don't know what I was thinking, but the language is of course regular, and can be given by `\d+([?]{3}\d+)*` regexp. Sorry for confusing you. Well, another proof that you shouldn't believe everything you read on the internet :)

Comment: The problem statements asks you to check whether the following is true: `if sum == n then count('?') == 3`. But you seem to be checking `if count('?') == 3 then sum == n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good job documenting the code!

Here are some of the things I would improve in the proposed code and also some random ideas and high-level thoughts:

- remove the `#---...--` lines - just use [2 blank lines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines) between the top-level blocks like function definitions
- you are overusing spaces in the expressions and statements. Remove the extra spaces after the `(` and before the `)`. When defining keyword arguments, [PEP8 recommends](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements) to not use spaces, e.g. `chars=string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits` (no spaces around the `=`)
- *variable and function naming issues*. `str_generrator` should probably be renamed to something more descriptive like `generate_input_string()` or `generate_test_string()`. Variable names like `str` and `string` *shadowing* the built-in `str` and the imported `string` module. We can also use some more descriptive names elsewhere - e.g. `desired_sum` instead of `num` in the `calc_additions()` function
- loop variable `c` is unused, use [`_` for this kind of throwaway variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python)
- `search_str` and `patterns` are unused in the `main()` function, remove them
- typo: `holdin` -> `holding`
- you can use a list comprehension together with an [extended unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) in the `calc_additions()` function:

  ```
  def calc_additions(desired_sum, strings):
      """docstring here
      """
      return [string
              for first_string, *_, last_string in strings
              if (int(first_string) + int(last_string)) == desired_sum]
  ```
- you can use [`f-strings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) to report results. Consider, may be, even using a *multi-line* `f-string`, like:

  ```
  print(f"""
  Search string  : {search_str}
  Patterns found : {patterns}
  Valid patterns : {calc_additions( 10, patterns)}""")
  ```
- using [type annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) would also be a good idea to improve on self-documenting
- you can *pre-compile the regular expression* using `re.compile()` and then using it to call `findall()` on
- also, look into [`.finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) to have an iterator and avoid having an extra list of matches
- it might also make sense to use a [regular expression *verbose mode*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE) to improve readability of the expression
- what if you would initialize `random.SystemRandom()` instance once and re-use?